# Can't JSON.parse Woocommerce REST API response in Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, woocommerce-rest-api

Product update works great via Woo Rest API, but I can't parse JSON response. JSON string response looks correct and valid, but **when I call** `JSON.parse(json);` **function JSON Object looks messy.** I can't imagine Woocommerce return wrong formatted JSON response. According to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ JSON validator, the response valid  (RFC 4627). **I have no idea why** `JSON.parse()` **doesn't work.** :/

My code and its response

```
var url = "https://domain.hu/wp-json/wc/v3/products/" + productID + "?consumer_key=" + apiusername + "&consumer_secret=" + apisecretkey;
var options = {
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'method' : 'put',
    'payload' : APIPayloadObject
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var json = response.getContentText();
```

At this point the respons looks correct, but it is not an Object:

```
{
    "id": 2624,
    "name": "Mof\u00e9m Euroszt\u00e1r mosd\u00f3 csaptelep leereszt\u0151 szelep n\u00e9lk\u00fcl?",
    "slug": "mofem-eurosztar-mosdo-csaptelep-leereszto-szelep-nelkul",
    "permalink": "https:\/\/aeco.hu\/termek\/mofem-eurosztar-mosdo-csaptelep-leereszto-szelep-nelkul\/",
    "date_created": "2019-03-18T20:48:54",
    "date_created_gmt": "2019-03-18T19:48:54",
    "date_modified": "2019-08-11T18:40:26",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2019-08-11T17:40:26",
    "type": "simple",
    "status": "publish",
    ...
```

If I run `var APIresponse = JSON.parse(json);` the content of the variable looks like this:

```
{upsell_ids=[], featured=false, purchasable=true, grouped_products=[], _links={self=[{href=https://aeco.hu/wp-json/wc/v3/products/2624}], collection=[{href=https://aeco.hu/wp-json/wc/v3/products}]}, tax_status=taxable, catalog_visibility=hidden, type=simple, external_url=, price=7198, meta_data=[{id=32677, value=323, key=supplier_stock_qty}, {id=62052, value=2-3 hét, key=supplier_shipping_time_backorder}, {id=64328, value=, key=_woosea_brand}, {id=64329, value=, key=_woosea_mpn},...
```

Do you have why JSON.parse() doesn't work? Thank you,

Comment: Could you please clarify why do you think it doesn't work? It is just how logger represents an object parsed by `JSON.parse()`? Are you worried that properties are returned in a different order?

Comment: It just looks messy in the logger, but it's a valid JSON.

Comment: For example, how about adding the script of `var obj = JSON.parse(json); var s = JSON.stringify(obj);` to your script and comparing the values between `json` and `s`?

Comment: You are right guys I made a mistake. There is no error in `JSON.parse()`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. There is no error in JSON.parse(). Thank you.